# Backup and restore FileTable files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, filetable

I'm preparing to use [the FileTable feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx) in SQL Server 2012, but I'm unclear about how backups work with this feature:

1. Does a full database backup include `FileTable` files?
2. How would I perform the restore of a single file, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does a full database backup include FileTable files?

Yes it does include the filetable data. From [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492061.aspx) :

> When you use SQL Server to back up a FileTable, the FILESTREAM data is backed up with the structured data in the database. If you do not want to back up FILESTREAM data with relational data, you can use a partial backup to exclude FILESTREAM filegroups.

-

> How would I perform the restore of a single file, for example?

You can use the same restore concept and do a point-in-time restore with STOPAT parameter.

For detailed example refer to (Page 319): [Backup and Restore for FILESTREAM Databases](http://download.red-gate.com/ebooks/SQL/Art_of_SS_Filestream_Sebastian_and_Aelterman.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, @kin!
I'll do some tests and report the results.

Comment: @CamilaReis if the answer is useful please upvote/mark as answer.

Comment: @CamilaReis you can have your question more meaningful by adding what tests (along with scripts) you did and what was the results. It will help future visitors.

Comment: Sorry. As my case was simple, I conducted the test did not use scripts, did the tests using the wizard from SQL Server.
I did the backup database, removed some files and restored the backup again. And everything was restored without any problem. Thank you! @Kin